# After enabling hardware virtualization, Windows 7 says it's not genuine

Tags: windows-7, windows-genuine-advantage, hardware-virtualization

I had to enable hardware virtualization to run an IE7 VPC image. For some reason this makes my Windows installation think that it's not genuine. This in turn also makes Microsoft Security Essentials report that it will stop working in 30 days.

I've disabled hardware virtualization and the problem is gone. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call up MSFT and tell them, they'll help you along the (re)activation.

Comment: Windows validates again when I disable hardware virtualization. So I was hoping it can be fixed without calling Microsoft Support. But if it can't, I will call them.

Comment: Yes, it's being triggered because of the CPU "change". Reactivation is painless, if a bit long-winded, over the phone.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed this update yet? [KB977206](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977206)

You don't need to enable hardware virtualization run XP mode.  I believe this goes for VPC as well.

Comment: I was under the impression that the update only works for Windows XP mode and not for VPC, but I will try it out.

Comment: The blog article I'm looking at states VPC and XP mode, althought I don't see VPC on the KB article.  I believe this is based on the same gizmos and gadgets (technical term, I swear) so you should be good.